# Can you implement a control algorithm and send the inputs via xbee?

Tags: wireless, xbee, control-system, pid-controller, uav

I know this question is little bit vague, but let's say that I have a robot or a quadrotor to control. I want to implement the control algorithm (PID, robust, or LQR) in the PC not in the robot/quad, to receive the feedback and send the inputs via xbee.

Can the xbee keep up, and do all the receiving and sending the inputs and the feedback, without delays?

One xbee is in the robot/quad and the other is plugged to the PC. You can say it's a 6 degree of freedom, (six variables) what type of xbee? I haven't got one yet, so can the cheapest do that, or the average one?

Answer (score 1):

No, you can't do it without delays. Any communications link is going to incur some kind of delay, and you will have to account for those delays in your control loop.

Comment: how much delay??,can i set my main loop at 0.001s (sampling time)

Comment: That depends entirely on how much data you're sending back and forth, what the communications bandwidth is, and the specific protocol you choose. Your question is too broad to give specific answers.

Comment: the question is too broad,i thought so,the thing is i'm just planing and exploring, i haven't emplimented anything yet,but thanks any way